# share argument between all fragments

Tags: android

I am making a bottom navigation app and want to share data between all fragments, for example clicking a button to share a name for all action bars. With safeArgs I can only send data to one fragment.
And I want to ask, is any solutions for global arguments(global variables) like redux in react native or provider in flutter?

Thank you

Comment: You can have functions/variables in activity of those fragments which will be shared across the fragments and manipulate them whenever you want in any fragment.

Comment: If you are using `MVVM` with Android `ViewModels` you can share this via an Activity ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use shareviewmodel, it's best practice
- Link refer: [viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Answer (score -1):

EDITED

Just create a `public` variable as a class variable in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   public int myVar; // outside of all methods
   ...
```

Then you have access it everywhere in your Fragments inside that MainActivity, like this:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());

if (mainActivity != null)
    mainActivity.myVar = 15;
```

Comment: there's really no need to be doing this, this is a bad practice to be using

Comment: why? can you explain please?

Comment: `share argument between all fragments` if these fragments use the same base activity, you can save the data in the activity but there's no need to be using static variables, this just creates a code smell when you start using statics for accessing data and you are quite likely to create a memory leak potentially as well

Comment: tnx! always learning... I fixed my code.